# "resetable" boolean array - use vector or regular array? how to "reset"?

Tags: c++

I'm using boolean array to store flags (something like "changed"). Size of the array is static, known at compile time.

Periodically i need to reset array, i.e. set all elements to `false`.  Should I use regular array and somethink like `memset` or `memcpy` to "reset" array to `false`? Or probaly you can suggest more robust solution?

Comment: `std::vector<bool> vec; vec.assign(vec.size(), false);` (or `vec.assign({ false, false, false, false, ... etc });` if you can/want to use C++11.)

Comment: what is the difference between `std::fill` and `vec.assign`?

Comment: Why not simply using [`std::bitset<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)? It will even use less space in memory than a `std::vector<bool>`.

Comment: bitset sounds fine, i didn't know it exist

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yup, that's even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::bitset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/) has the `reset()` function that without parameters resets all bits.